# How to completely turn off session saving?

Tags: startup, session

I opened *System ➜ Preferences ➜ Startup Applications  ➜ Options* and clicked on *Remember Currently Running Application*. I suppose this makes Ubuntu memorize (save a list on some place in disk) all currently running applications and when you reboot your computer, the OS starts with everything in that list.

Now I want to get rid of it. Of course I can close all applications which I do not want to start in startup, and click *Remember currently running Applications* again, but this doesn't seem to work as expected. For example, Yakuake opens differently if I do that.

What I want is to completely turn off session saving. Maybe I can delete the stored information somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `man gnome-session`:

> The gnome-session program starts up the GNOME desktop environment. This  command
>          is  typically  executed  by  your login manager (either gdm, xdm, or from your X
>          startup scripts). It will load either your saved session, or it will  provide  a
>          default  session  for  the  user  as defined by the system administrator (or the
>          default GNOME installation on your system).
>
> The default session is defined in the GConf keys  under  `/desktop/gnome/session`.
>          **When saving a session, gnome-session saves the currently running applications in
>          the `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gnome-session/saved-session` directory.**
>
> gnome-session is an X11R6 session manager. It can manage GNOME  applications  as
>          well as any X11R6 SM compliant.

<sup>*(Emphasis mine)*</sup>

By default `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is `~/.config` so that is where the saved applications data is stored.

Remove all the files in that folder to "forget" the last running applications:

```
rm ~/.config/gnome-session/saved-session/*
```